# Adding transition animation breaking tooltip mouseover

Tags: d3.js

I am adding animations to my scatterplot points in my d3.js line graph and when I added them in I noticed that the it broke my mouseover event listener for the tooltips that appear for each circle. The error message that I am receiving `Uncaught Error: unknown type: mouseover` and I'm wondering why the animation would break the event listener. Is it because I have it in the chain for the circle earlier than the event listener meaning that it is trying to call the method on the animation rather than the circle?

Here is my code:

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>

<style>
div.tooltip {   
    position: absolute;         
    text-align: center;         
    width: 100px;                   
    height: 30px;                   
    padding: 2px;               
    font: 12px sans-serif;      
    background: lightsteelblue; 
    border: 0px;        
    border-radius: 8px;         
    pointer-events: none;           
}
</style>

<script>

    var data = [
        { "x": "2020-04-26", "y": 461.0, "label": "7:41" },
        { "x": "2020-04-27", "y": 421.0, "label": "7:01" },
        { "x": "2020-04-28", "y": 519.0, "label": "8:39" },
        { "x": "2020-04-29", "y": 502.0, "label": "8:22" },
        { "x": "2020-04-30", "y": 511.0, "label": "8:31" },
        { "x": "2020-05-01", "y": 513.0, "label": "8:33" }
    ]
    
    // D3 date parser
    for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
        var parser = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")
        data[i].date = parser(data[i].x);
    }

    console.log(data)
    var margin = { top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60  }
    var width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right;
    var height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


    // Define the div for the tooltip
    var div = d3.select("body").append("div")   
        .attr("class", "tooltip")               
        .style("opacity", 0);

    var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
        .append("svg")
            .attr( 'preserveAspectRatio',"xMinYMin meet")
            .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + (width + margin.left + margin.right) + " " + (height + margin.top + margin.bottom))
        .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")"); // translate(margin left, margin top)

    var x = d3.scaleTime()
        .domain([d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.date }), d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.date })])
        .range([0, width]);
    
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    // text label for the x axis
    svg.append("text")             
        .attr("transform",
                "translate(" + (width/2) + " ," + (height + margin.top + 20) + ")")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Date");

    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){ return +d.y })])
        .range([height, 0]);
    
    svg.append("g")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

    // text label for the y axis
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 0 - margin.left)
        .attr("x",0 - (height / 2))
        .attr("dy", "1em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Time Asleep (Minutes)");

    // Add line path
    svg.append("path")
        .datum(data)
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
        .attr("d", d3.line()
            .x(function(d) { return x(d.date) })
            .y(function(d) { return y(d.y) })
        );

    // Add the scatterplot (data points)
    svg.selectAll("dot")
        .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("r", 3)
        .transition()
        .delay(function(d,i){ return (i*3)})
        .duration(2000)
        .attr("cx", function(d){ return x(d.date) })
        .attr("cy", function(d){ return y(d.y) })
        // Add tooltip on hover
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {
            div.transition()
                .duration(200)
                .style("opacity", .9);
            div.html(d.x + "<br/>" + d.label)
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 30) + "px")
        })
        // Remove tooltip after hover
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {
            div.transition()
                .duration(500)
                .style("opacity", 0);
        });
    

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.on` is not part of a `transition`, you must put it before the transition. Try something like this:

```
.enter()
.append("circle")
.attr("r", 3)
// Add tooltip on hover
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
    div.transition()
        .duration(200)
        .style("opacity", .9);
    div.html(d.x + "<br/>" + d.label)
        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 30) + "px")
})
// Remove tooltip after hover
.on("mouseout", function(d) {
    div.transition()
        .duration(500)
        .style("opacity", 0);
})
.transition()
.delay(function(d,i){ return (i*3)})
.duration(2000)
.attr("cx", function(d){ return x(d.date) })
.attr("cy", function(d){ return y(d.y) });
```

Comment: Great, just as I had expected! That worked, although you may want to edit your answer to remove the `;` from the `.on("mouseout") method

Comment: Sorry, I was on my phone. Good catch. I am glad it worked.